# How to redirect the user depending on the browser locale without losing any ranking

Tags: php, redirect, web, seo, multilingual

I currently have a website which is only in English. This site is already indexed in search engines. I'm translating it and my new URL is like this :

- English: http://www.mywebsite.com/en/controller/method
- French: http://www.mywebsite.com/fr/controller/method

I would like that when a user load a page on the site **without any locale** in the URL, he would be redirected to a new URL *with his browser locale in it*.
My problem is **not how to do that**, but I would like to do not lose any ranking in search engines, and I don't know if `301` redirections would be enough as search engines will be redirected to two different URLs depending on the locale they give...

**Will Google understand ?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines do not generally send a browser locale (Accept-Language HTTP headers). That means they will only see whatever you implement as default option for requests without locale information, which should probably English since that is already indexed.

All other standard rules regarding redirects apply.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the answer I was looking forward to.

Comment: However, this is something they surely do check in order to prevent cloaking and similar techniques. Regardless- modern search engines are likely smart enough to understand that what you are doing is not bad.